# vertical and horizontal alignment at the same time does not work

Tags: css

I am using bootstrap to layout my website.
Everything is fine except the vertical alignment of the text "THIS IS TEST". I used different ways which I found in the web such as combination of vertical-align: middle and text-align: center  and flex box. None of these generated the right vertical alignment. Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet"    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
   <style>
 .header{

 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 30px;
 background-color: #4070CB;
color: #EFF0F2;
height:60px;

}
.txt{
  align-items :center;
  display : flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
 .rightImg{
  margin-right:30px;
  margin-left:12px;
  }
.leftImg{
margin-right:12px;
margin-left:30px;
}

</style>
 </head>
 <body>

<div class="container col-sm-offset-1">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-10 header">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1 leftImg"><img   src="http://image.flaticon.com/sprites/authors/28-simpleicon.png" alt="Smiley   face" height="36" width="36"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 txt">THIS IS A TEST</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 rightImg"><img  src="http://image.flaticon.com/sprites/authors/28-simpleicon.png" alt="Smiley   face" height="36" width="36"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

Also here is the jfiddle link to my code:
[jfiddle](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB10AIM52BPG)

Can anyone help? How can I vertically align the text in the header?

Comment: Your parent element has a defined height of 60px. Use `line-height: 60px` to center a line of text vertically in a 60px container. This won't fix your Bootstrap issues with the columns not floating though - don't know what's going on there.

Comment: can you explain how exactly you want the output...little unclear about output

Comment: @JonUleis thanks for answering. If I use line height it shrinks my dive but I want the exact height of 60

Comment: @HamedMinaee Nothing about line-height should shrink your div - something else is messing it up if that's the case.

Comment: @Geeky Sure, thanks for answering. Actually I need two rows. the forst for header which I am currently stuck with that and the second is body. The header contains two images on the sides and a header text. But the text should be verticallyy and horizontally aligned. Also the header should have a height of 60 px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is centered vertically, but in relation to the row, not the header.

To vertically align everything in the header, you could replace the height with a padding.

```
.header {
   padding: 15px 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can apply a margin to your text.

```
.txt {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to double check since I am new to bootstrap. Do you think my bootstarp layout is correct?